# Selecting last child using jQuery function children()

Tags: jquery, children

How to select a child in particular through the jQuery function children() ?

I tried `.children('a:last-child')` to no avail.

Comment: would be great if you can share the html and relevant js code for problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this: use `:last`

```
.children('a:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe your browser don't supply the way to choose element `:last-child`,so you can try it like this:`.children('a').last()`